# What is a sensible Python unit testing environment in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, unit-testing

I develop Python libraries on a Mac, but I'd like to test them on Windows as well to make sure everything works there.

I am a test-driven developer and maintain full unit test coverage as well as application level acceptance/integration tests. I use `pytest` for unit testing and `behave` for acceptance tests.

I only use Windows for very specific tasks like making appointments with Outlook, but I do have a VMWare Fusion instance of Windows 7 running all the time. I could run my tests under Windows without having to use a different machine.

The trouble is, I'm not familiar with how folks typically run Python on Windows anymore, but would like to use a fairly typical setup so I would encounter similar problems to most Windows users before they install my libraries.

Back in my pre-Mac days, I would run Python 2.3 or 2.4 under Cygwin. But I'm not at all sure that was even typical then.

What kind of Python environment is a good one for testing Python code in a Windows environment?

Comment: What aspects of the environment do you need to know about?  Are you just asking how people install it?  I would imagine the simplest and most useful option is to just get the binary installers from python.org and install them.

Comment: I would use python for windows .... not python for cygwin (I think lots of people still use 2.7 and to a lesser extent 2.6) ... are you making executables? or python setup.py installers?

Comment: I develop on Python in Windows; if there is something specific I could answer it but to start off with - everyone uses the Windows binary installers (cygwin = no go).

Comment: Thanks for these, sounds like installing it with the binary installer (.msi I'm figuring) is the right way to get Python installed. Then do folks run python from the CMD.EXE window or is there some sort of Python app that comes with that the average user would use? I'm just thinking that as soon as you bring the CMD.EXE interface into it that would scare a bunch of folks away so thought maybe there was a friendly UI by now or something. I guess also the thought of using CMD.EXE to run anything after getting used to iTerm makes me shudder :)

Comment: @scanny there is a mini-python GUI that comes with the installation called Python IDLE. You can use it to run and generate scripts. But personally I just use CMD.exe to run the code and Notepad++ to edit it. Just seems easier to me than a GUI or IDE :)